# How to get User Followers in Instagram API?

Tags: php, api, oauth, instagram-api

I am using instagram API(oauth) and I able to get the access token and user information using

`https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/client_id='.$client_id.'&redirect_uri='.$redirect_url .'&response_type=code'`

and `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token` by passing client id, secret and redirect_uri.

when I make the first call
`(https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/client_id='.$client_id.'&redirect_uri='.$redirect_url .'&response_type=code')` it gives me the array of access_token and user.

My question is what should I do to get the followers of the user ?

I know I have to use `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` but for some reason I am getting the error message

```
{
 "code": 400, 
 "error_type": "OAuthException", 
 "error_message": "Only response type \"code\" and \"token\" is allowed"
}
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you don't need to be authenticated (i.e. need an `access_token`) to get a list of user followers. You just need your `client_id`.

The following request should work in your case:

**`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/follows/?client_id={client_id}`**

Answer (score 0):

As per new update you have to use access token instead of client_id

this is my response 
`{"data": {"id": "1829538552", "username": "mypageusername", "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/11084945_1580533368872297_743341297_a.jpg", "full_name": "pagename Nation", "bio": "For Business/Ads\add@gmail.com\nKik: @test", "website": "https://carsmydrug.myshopify.com/", "counts": {"media": 371, "follows": 6464, "followed_by": 171599}}, "meta": {"code": 200}}`

this is url to get above response
`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1829538552/?access_token=1829538552.81758e8.5d303d9dd94543efb17684dee425cb5a`

You have to get access token and you can only check follower list of user that accepted your of sandbox user